# How do I pipe to terminal and to program at the same time in bash

Tags: c, bash

So I am attempting to make a script to automate the testing(in and out) of my C program and I am trying to get the input to stay on screen so I know what is happening.

I have only tried piping so far:

```
foo < input.txt
```

and

```
cat input.txt | tee dev/tty |foo
```

which has yet to work for me.

So assuming the input file would look like:

```
123
321
```

Ideally, the IO would look like:

```
Input: 123
Echo: 123
Input: 321
Echo: 321
```

but it turns into

```
123
321
Input: 
Echo: 123
Input: 
Echo: 321
```

Are there other methods that I can use to test my C program? Where else can I tee to that can achieve such result? Is it possible for me to write another C program that can achieve something similar?

Comment: You're seeing the effects of buffering in the C standard library. It's probably not worth the trouble of trying to defeat it. If you want to watch your program run, do it in a debugger.

Comment: I don't actually want to "watch it run". I am more concerned with the output. If I can't see what's being input it makes it quite tedious trying to draw lines between the inputs and outputs.

Comment: Then add debugging statements to print the input to the same stream as the output.

Comment: You are missing a `/`.  `... | tee dev/tty | ...` should be `... | tee /dev/tty | ...`

Comment: Why don't you do that from within your program? Do u specifically need to do it with a script?

Comment: Maybe you should look at the `expect` program, and/or use pseudo-ttys.  If you need to worry about standard error too, it gets rather tricky.

Comment: This may help: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe

Answer (score 1):

The stdout of `tee` (to stdin of `foo`) and the duplicated writes (to your `tty` character dev) are not synchronized in time.  Your tty is consuming input faster than `foo` and the buffering of libc is making it even worse.  If interactive automation is what you seek, look to the `expect` program.

Answer (score 0):

how about simply

```
cat input.txt ; cat input.txt | foo ;
```

first part prints the input, second part prints the output.

Your alternative is to put print statements in your code so that the subpart of the input being treated  is printed before the associated output every iteration.

Comment: I need the input to be inline with the output. :(

Comment: there is no way for bash to only print the right pay of the input, unless you do a complex script that parses the output of your program

Answer (score 0):

The following script feeds input to the program when it detects that it is blocked in a `read()` syscall on the standard input, and it prints the same text on standard output. As a result the output of the program and the contents of the standard input are properly interleaved.

**Usage:**

`$ simulate_user_input` *`program args ...`*

**Example:**

```
$ cat > test_script <<'END'
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo -n "First name: "
read -r first_name
echo -n "Second name: "
read -r second_name
echo "Hello $first_name $second_name"
END                                  

$ chmod +x test_script
$ ./simulate_user_input ./test_script <<< $'John\nSmith'
First name: John
Second name: Smith
Hello John Smith
```

---

**simulate_user_input**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
    cat<<END

Usage:

    $(basename "$0") command args ...

END
    exit 1
fi

#set -x
if [ "$1" == "-simulate" ]
then
    app_stdin="$2/app_stdin"
    user_stdin="$2/user_stdin"
    user_stdout="$2/user_stdout"
    exec > "$app_stdin" 3< "$user_stdin" 4> "$user_stdout"
    while read -r -n 6 -t 0.1 line
    do
        if [[ $line == 'read(0' ]]
        then
            read -u 3 -r line || { cat > /dev/null; exit 0; }
            echo "$line" >&4
            echo "$line"
        fi
    done
    exit 0
fi

cleanup()
{
    rm -rf "$tmpdir"
    if [ "$(jobs -r|wc -l)" -ne 0 ]
    then
        kill %1 %2
    fi
}

tmpdir="$(mktemp -d)"
trap "cleanup" EXIT
app_stdin="$tmpdir/app_stdin"
user_stdin="$tmpdir/user_stdin"
user_stdout="$tmpdir/user_stdout"
mkfifo "$app_stdin"
mkfifo "$user_stdin"
mkfifo "$user_stdout"

cat "$app_stdin"|strace -e read -o "|$0 -simulate '$tmpdir'" "$@" &
cat < "$user_stdout" &
cat > "$user_stdin"
wait
```

Comment: Hi, when I attempt to run the test script using your instructions I get an exec error: "strace: exec: Exec format error". From what I have been told, execs on linux distros are all over the place. The linux I am running on is an openSUSE from 2011(I think) :(

Comment: @ZhengChen Does your program normally run without this script? What does "`file` *your_program*" show?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little Python 2 program that will do it, provided your target program (`foo`) is guaranteed to output one line for every line of input:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, subprocess
sp = subprocess.Popen(sys.argv[1:], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for input_line in sys.stdin:
    print('Input: ' + input_line.rstrip('\r\n'))
    sp.stdin.write(input_line)
    sp.stdin.flush()
    output_line = sp.stdout.readline()
    print('Output: ' + output_line.rstrip('\r\n'))
```

If you save this as `tee.py`, you can test it with

```
echo -e '123\n321' | tee.py cat -
```

for a generic reproducible test, or

```
echo -e '123\n321' | tee.py foo
```

for your specific example.

---

PS:  if you want it in Python 3, you have to alter two lines:

```
    sp.stdin.write(input_line.encode('utf-8'))
```

and

```
    output_line = sp.stdout.readline().decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: This works under the assumption that the input and output lines alternate. What if the program outputs several lines in a row before requesting some input?

Comment: Yes, that is a limitation of this solution.  Also, it will fail in the converse case, if several lines of input are required before spitting out a line of output (then it will just hang).